# how to remove specification / notations from google graph?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Using `google.visualization` to populating the graph in MVC 5 web application.

Want to remove black circled notation line from graph from bellow
[image]

What settings I have to do ? 
Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var rows = new Array();
        var jsonData = '@Html.Raw(@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject((List<ChartDTO>)Model.Charts.ToList()))';        
        $.each($.parseJSON(jsonData), function () {          
            rows.push([parseInt(this.UserCount)]);
        }); 

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', ''],
          ['Jan', parseInt(rows[0])],
          ['Feb', parseInt(rows[1])],
          ['Mar', parseInt(rows[2])],
          ['Apr', parseInt(rows[3])],
          ['May', parseInt(rows[4])],
          ['Jun', parseInt(rows[5])],
          ['Jul', parseInt(rows[6])],
          ['Aug', parseInt(rows[7])],
          ['Sep', parseInt(rows[8])],
          ['Oct', parseInt(rows[9])],
          ['Nov', parseInt(rows[10])],
          ['Dec', parseInt(rows[11])]
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Traffic',
            vAxis: {title: "Registrations", viewWindow: { min: 0 }},
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            series: { 0: { color: 'red' } },
            hAxis: { title: "Months" },
            'chartArea': { 'width': '80%', 'height': '70%' },
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the legend by using `'none'` as the position:

```
legend: {position: 'none'}
```

**Example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

    var rows = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        rows.push(getRandomInt(0, 100));
    }


    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Month', ''],
         ['Jan', parseInt(rows[0])],
         ['Feb', parseInt(rows[1])],
         ['Mar', parseInt(rows[2])],
         ['Apr', parseInt(rows[3])],
         ['May', parseInt(rows[4])],
         ['Jun', parseInt(rows[5])],
         ['Jul', parseInt(rows[6])],
         ['Aug', parseInt(rows[7])],
         ['Sep', parseInt(rows[8])],
         ['Oct', parseInt(rows[9])],
         ['Nov', parseInt(rows[10])],
         ['Dec', parseInt(rows[11])]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Traffic',
        vAxis: { title: "Registrations", viewWindow: { min: 0 } },
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        series: { 0: { color: 'red' } },
        hAxis: { title: "Months" },
        'chartArea': { 'width': '80%', 'height': '70%' },
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    
}


function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```